# Cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable error in Java

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am stuck since morning figuring this thing out (wasted nearly 6-7 hours) and could not do anything.

[image]

I was trying to add RestEasy module in my web app. Added few dependencies but somehow my api calls were not working. So removed it and this exception started floating around.

Things I tried: -

1. Did a complete `git checkout .` Build the project. Did not work.
2. Tried reimporting the project in IntellijIdea 13 (which I am using). It did not help either.
3. Deleted my local `.m2` folder and downloaded every dependency again.
4. Restarted my system couple of times.

The project builds just fine. But when I try running it - Tomcat 7.0.56 - this exception appears. Did whatever I could, but nothing worked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, its not less than a Eureka moment for me. I tried figuring out the soltion and found out that my project's Spring Facet was not properly set up. Now when I try fixing that, there is one more issue -

[image]

For this error, try removing the source root of the module. It will be added later on its own. Now when the source root is removed, the Spring Facet is easily fixed.

After adding Spring library, just rebuild the project and start the server.

[image]